# How to update nested data react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a form with some nested data update. The code is as below:

On Change method

```
let student = {
        name: null,
        marks: { english: null },
    };
const handleChange = (updatedValue) => {
    student = {
        ...student,
        ...updatedValue,
        marks: { ...updatedValue.marks },
    };
    console.log(student);
};
```

And my JSX:

```
<input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            id="name"
                            placeholder="Name"
                            value={student.name ?? ""}
                            onChange={(event) =>
                                handleChange({
                                    name: event.target.value,
                                })
                            }
                        />
<input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="english"
                                placeholder="English"
                                value={student.marks.english ?? ""}
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                    handleChange({
                                        marks: { english: event.target.value },
                                    })
                                }
                            />
```

The problem is that for "name" it works fine. But for "english", it behaves abnormally.
E.g. when I enter "1" in English, it updates it to 1 in the console but on the UI, it immediately disappears from the input box. Also if I update it to 2, the value is replaced from one to 2.

The the expected value is 1

Can someone please help me identifying how to update the nested values correctly from the input box?

Comment: why this `value={student.name ?? ""}`

Comment: @sushildlh Just to make sure if there is nothing in student.name. "" will be taken

Comment: use `|` not `??`. ALso are you updating state or doing direct manipulation on object?

Comment: @sushildlh Using | did not solved the problem. I am not updating state as of now. I am just trying to get the value and update it on console.

Comment: The issue remained same

Comment: Got the problem, let me answer it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247072/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-vibhor-goyal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use state to store data

```
let student = {
    name: null,
    marks: { english: null },
};
```

change to

```
const [student, setStudent] = useState({
    name: null,
    marks: { english: null },
});

const handleChange = (updatedValue) => {
  setStudent(student => ({
    ...student,
    ...updatedValue,
    marks: { ...student.marks, ...updatedValue.marks },
  }))
};
```

Comment: I am not trying to set state as of now. I am just trying to store the values in the student variable from input.

Comment: if you want to update ui you must use state

Comment: I am not trying to update UI. I am just trying to update the variable

Comment: it will fix issue with disappearing from input box, and save student as you expected

Comment: IT did not fixed the issue. Please check the sandbox code - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-worker-09ed1z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you should log student not in handleChange method, check this https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-noether-o2fbht?file=/src/components/form.component.js